# Upload and display picture in PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my form in html (I'm using xampp):

Slika=picture

```
     <form name = "my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
method = "POST" action = "skripta.php">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="slika">Slika</label>
            <input type="file" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/gif" name="slika" class="form controlfile" id="slika">
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to upload it into folder called images and display it:
This is what I have done in php:

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
   {
      $naslov=$_POST['naslov'];
      $sazetak=$_POST['sazetak'];
      $slika=$_POST['slika'];
         
    $fileName = $_FILES['slika']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['slika']['tmp_name'];
    
    $dir = "images/";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir . $fileName);
    echo "Success";
}
```

I got these errors:
Line 50 in php is fileName, 51 tmpName

> Notice: Undefined index: slika in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\skripta.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\skripta.php on line 50
>
> Notice: Undefined index: slika in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\skripta.php on line 51
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\projekt\skripta.php on line 51

Comment: which line is line 50 ?

Comment: How is `<form ` tag defined?

Comment: fileName=line 50

tmp name=line 51, it has form

Comment: add this to your html form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the entire form. Also, is there any PHP code that comes before what you've shown?

Comment: What happens when you remove `accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/gif"`? You could always check that on the back-end...

Comment: I managed to upload file, but i dont know how to display it.
<img class="card-img-left" >
             <?php echo'<img src= "images/"slika>'; ?> or

Comment: @Zvone when you are managed to upload the file then you need to refer the absolute path of image in IMG tag. <img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/file_uploaded.extension" >